# MySQL Distinct and LEFT JOIN returns duplicate

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have 2 tables in my database. One named `data`, another named `changes`.

The table's columns are

`Data`

```
------------
|id | name |
|-----------
|1  | Test |
|2  | Hello|
------------
```

`changes`

```
------------------------------------
|id | name | related_id | Comments |
|-----------------------------------
|1  | Test |     1      |  Example |
|2  | Hello|     2      | Example2 |
|3  | Hello|     2      | Example3 |
------------------------------------
```

As you can see, `changes`.`related_id` is a foreign key to `data`.`id`.
`changes` can have multiple rows of same `name` and `related_id` and different comments.

After running this query, I realized that multiple rows are returned where for example, `Hello` can appear 2 times.

`SELECT DISTINCT data.name, changes.comments FROM data LEFT JOIN changes ON data.id = changes.related_id`

`Result`

```
--------------------
|name   | comments |
|-------------------
|Hello  | Example2 |
|Hello  | Example3 |
--------------------
```

How do I go about making sure that only 1 row is returned? I went about SO to look for answers and many stated using `DISTINCT`, yet it's not working in my case.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You get 2 different records returned. Which comment should be returned and why?

Comment: Any records can returned. I only wanted a unique `name` with any associated data. Is that possible?

Comment: If you only need the `name`, then only select the  `name`: `SELECT DISTINCT data.name FROM data ...` But then you actually don't even need a `join`

Comment: if user have more than one comment, then you will get duplicate name but not record. if you want unique name, then don't select any field from left table and use distinct

Comment: @juergend But I would like to have any associated data from `changes`  table to return with the `name`. Just that if there are more than 1 row, return the one with the last inserted id. In my case, "Hello" will return ONLY `id` of 3 and `comments`of "Example3"

Comment: @kumar_v I don't really get what you mean by that. Do you mind explaining a little? Thanks!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If you want only one record for every name in your `data` table and it can be **any** record, then you can group by the unique column (`name`) and use an aggregate function on the other column like `max()`

```
SELECT data.name, max(changes.comments)
FROM data 
LEFT JOIN changes ON data.id = changes.related_id
GROUP BY data.name
```

Comment: this is just wow..mysql has no row number / partition functions

Comment: Great! You manage to solve my problem! Thank you so much! Learnt something new today :)